# Magento URL Rewrite how to change the format of generated product URL

Tags: magento-1.9

Does anybody has a proper solution for rewriting Product URL's in the following format:

http://domain/{product_id}_{title}

And furthermore get rid of the prefix Magento pastes before the title in case of duplicates.

Comment: I'm sure that Stack Overflow is more than capable of helping with this question.  However, I just want to point out that there is a [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/) as well and they may be able to help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the function "_refresh Product Rewrite" of the class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url.

Change

```
if ($product->getUrlKey() == '') {
    $urlKey = $this->getProductModel()->formatUrlKey($product->getName());
    }else {
    $urlKey = $this->getProductModel()->formatUrlKey($product>getUrlKey());
}
```

for

```
if ($product->getUrlKey() == '') {
   $urlKey = $this->getProductModel()->formatUrlKey($product->getId(). '_' .$product->getName());
} else {
   $urlKey = $this->getProductModel()->formatUrlKey($product->getId(). '_' .$product->getName());
}
```

You need or create a module or copy the file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php to app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/ Model/Url.php

After reindexer catalog_url